# xparse: missing space after document command expansion

Tags: macros, formatting, xparse

I'm having a problem with the below code. It's the smallest I could make the example.

I'm working on a document with an index of persons, and have for this purpose created a command for each person. It has an optional parameter which overrides the "default name". So `\JensHansen` prints "Jens Hansen" and `\JensHansen{Jens}` prints "Jens" but both create entries in the index.

However, in the first case, there is no space after Hansen, which clashes when the next word is just a normal word as in the last lines below becoming "Jens Hansenliked to walk the country roads" or "A man told Jens Hansento leave"...

If I put a space in the command, it results in the quotes & apostrophes being preceded by a space. I've put an `\underline` in the command for legibility but it will be removed in the final version.

It likely has to do with the `\Fallback` command's optional argument but I'm not sure how...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\DeclareDocumentCommand\Fallback{ m m }{\IfNoValueF{#1}{#1}\IfNoValueT{#1}{#2}}

% underline just for clarity
\DeclareDocumentCommand\person{ m g }{\underline{\index{#1}{\Fallback{#2}{#1}}}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\JensHansen{ g }{\person{Jens Hansen}{#1}}

\begin{document}

There was a man named \JensHansen, who usually just went by \JensHansen{Jens}.
Sometimes, he even went by ``\JensHansen{Nysteds Skraek}!''
\JensHansen{Jens}' father was named Hans.
\JensHansen liked to walk the country roads. % space following Hansen is missing!
A man told \JensHansen to leave. % again!

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, I presume, simply the basic `TeX` fact that control words `\foo` should be keyed `\foo{} bar` or `\foo\ bar` for the space after `\foo` not to be removed by `TeX` tokenization parser.

Look perhaps the [xspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package. Or at least read its documentation as I presume it explains the underlying facts (which should be in any basic document introducing to LaTeX).

Comment: Using an empty {} will cause the commands to render nothing (because I'm now providing an empty replacement for the default name). So I guess I'll have to write the commands differently, but how?

Comment: glad it helped. As per your first comment, using `{..}` for optional argument is a bit, hmm, I am looking for the word, perverse ? braces have such a deep role in the default `TeX` set-up... the usual convention is to use brackets `[...]`.